# Updating FusionChart component with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, fusioncharts

An html page contains FusionCharts component.
Below this component are a couple of html controls supposed to filter date for this component.
Initially, there was a problem updating the chart component, upon clicking "Filter" button
I used the following code:

```
currentChart.setDataURL(url);
currentChart.render("ChartDiv");
```

It didn't work. It merely reloaded the same url. It worked only when I started to nullify previous chart object and created a new one at the same place, instead of updating

```
currentChart = new FusionCharts('/FusionCharts/Maps/FCMap_WorldwithCountries.swf', "countryChart", "550", "200", "0", "1");
currentChart.setDataURL(url);
currentChart.render("ChartDiv");
```

Am I right that one cannot update existing chart object, only recreate it with a new url?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try with the following code to update your chart dynamically?

```
var fc = getChartFromId("countryChart");
fc.setDataURL(url);
```